# Add a watermark on a pdf that contains images using pdfbox (1.7)

Tags: pdfbox

I have used the code suggested in:

[PDFBox Overlay fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095822/pdfbox-overlay-fails/32269009#32269009)

to add a watermark to an existing pdf.
Unfortunately, the pdf produced is corrupted. The pdf reader complains when I open the document: *"An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem"*.

The document is opened but it does not show the images.

It seems to happen with all the pdfs. It could be worth saying that it happens also with a different implementation that simply uses the Overlay class.

The following url points to a pdf that I used for my testing:

[A pdf with an image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7hG2Ap47MTKMEpqZkpudG1CYjg/view?usp=sharing)

The code to test this transformation is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDExtendedGraphicsState;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.MapUtil;

/**
 * This test is about overlaying with special effect.
 * 
 * @author mkl
 */
public class OverlayWithEffect
{
    final static File RESULT_FOLDER = new File("target/test-outputs", "assembly");

    public static void overlayWithDarkenBlendMode(PDDocument document, PDDocument overlay) throws IOException
    {
        PDXObjectForm xobject = importAsXObject(document, (PDPage) overlay.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0));
        PDExtendedGraphicsState darken = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
        darken.getCOSDictionary().setName("BM", "Darken");

        List<PDPage> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

        for (PDPage page: pages)
        {
            if (page.getResources() == null) {
                page.setResources(page.findResources());
            }

            if (page.getResources() != null) {
                Map<String, PDExtendedGraphicsState> states = page.getResources().getGraphicsStates();
                if (states == null) {
                    states = new HashMap<String, PDExtendedGraphicsState>();
                }
                String darkenKey = MapUtil.getNextUniqueKey(states, "Dkn");
                states.put(darkenKey, darken);
                page.getResources().setGraphicsStates(states);
                PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, false, true);
                stream.appendRawCommands(String.format("/%s gs ", darkenKey));
                stream.drawXObject(xobject, 0, 0, 1, 1);
                stream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static PDXObjectForm importAsXObject(PDDocument target, PDPage page) throws IOException
    {
        final PDStream xobjectStream = new PDStream(target, page.getContents().createInputStream(), false);
        final PDXObjectForm xobject = new PDXObjectForm(xobjectStream);

        xobject.setResources(page.findResources());
        xobject.setBBox(page.findCropBox());

        COSDictionary group = new COSDictionary();
        group.setName("S", "Transparency");
        group.setBoolean(COSName.getPDFName("K"), true);
        xobject.getCOSStream().setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Group"), group);

        return xobject;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws COSVisitorException, IOException
    {
        InputStream sourceStream = new FileInputStream("x:/pdf-test.pdf");
        InputStream overlayStream = new FileInputStream("x:/draft.pdf");
        try {
            final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceStream);
            final PDDocument overlay = PDDocument.load(overlayStream);

            overlayWithDarkenBlendMode(document, overlay);

            document.save("x:/da-draft-5.pdf");
            document.close();
        }
        finally {
            sourceStream.close();
            overlayStream.close();
        }
    }    
}
```

I am using version 1.7 of pdfbox.

Thanks

Comment: *The following url points to a pdf that I used for my testing:* - Is that the document you use as watermark or is it the one to which the watermark shall be applied? Can you supply (an example for) the missing one?

Comment: I just overlayed your PDF with its own first page. Thus, it has been used in both roles. But the produced PDF is *not* corrupted, especially Adobe Reader does not complain. Your description, therefore, is missing some information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to test it. The watermark I used is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7hG2Ap47MTKTjdfbzl5Q3pZUk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Using your shared files I still could not reproduce the issue. [OverlayWithEffect.testOverlayWithDarkenMarcoAltieri2()](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/assembly/OverlayWithEffect.java) overlays pdf-test.pdf with draft1.pdf, and the result is as expected.

Comment: You edited your question to include *I am using version 1.7 of pdfbox.* - that is a pretty old version. Try using the current 1.8.10.

Comment: Using your exact code (with merely the file paths differing) and PDFBox 1.8.10 I still could not  reproduce your issue. [OverlayWithEffect.main()](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/OverlayWithEffect.java) overlays pdf-test.pdf with draft1.pdf, and the result is as expected.

Comment: Not so easy to upgrade... I have to check if the new version is compatible with the rest of the application (an open source CMS)

Comment: But I think that you are right. It should be a bug in this version.

Comment: I suggest you just delete the question. People shouldn't start with old versions.

Comment: People will start with old versions given that these old versions are still in use in major products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by mkl, it is probably an issue with the version of pdfbox that I am using.